# Vertical and horizontal lines in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make this line(see picture) with CSS?

[image: this]

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: So you want to show these lines above the picture and what did you do so far for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Using [pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) as `:after`

```css
div{
height:80px;
width:3px;
background:black;
border-radius: 23%;
position:relative;
}
div:after{
content:'';
height:3px;
width:170px;
background:black;
border-radius: 23%;
position:absolute;
top:47%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need complex code, one element and few CSS lines are enough:

```css
.line {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border-left:5px solid;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/100% 5px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.line {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  padding:48px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-left:5px solid;
  background:#000 content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution I've seen so far

Comment: Seems like you are highly skilled with `background:linear-gradient`, :) :) 
Can you please help me in learning those tricks !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```css
.line1 {
  height:150px;
  width:3px;
  background:#000;
  position:relative;
}

.line2 {
  height:5px;
  width:300px;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
/* following 2 code is excellent center  for second line. */
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line1">
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```